# completeness of the metric $[1,2]\times[1,2]\rightarrow \mathbb R:$ $d(x,y)=|x^4-y^4|$

Tags: general-topology, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

I must determine if the following space is complete

> $[1,2]\times[1,2]\rightarrow \mathbb R:$  $d(x,y)=|x^4-y^4|$.
>
> Is $([1,2],d) $complete?

my try:

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a Cauchy sequence

by definition

$\forall \epsilon, \exists n_0, \forall n,m \geq n_0 $    $d(x_n,x_m)\leq \epsilon$

$4|x_n-x_m| \leq|x_n^4- x_m^4|\leq256|x_n-x_m|$

then I don't know how to continue
Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way that uses the inequality you just found. We have 
$$ 4|x_n - x_m| \leq |x_n^4 - x_m^4| \leq \epsilon.$$
So $(x_n)_{n \geq 1}$ is Cauchy in the usual metric. Note $\mathbb{R}$ is complete with its usual metric. In fact $[1, 2]$ is complete with its usual metric as well. (Why?) Can you reason from here why your space is complete?

Comment: that is actually the part I am having trouble with. I know that open domains:(a,b) are not complete by the trick of making a sequence convergent to a or b, like a-1/n, and that on closed intervals that does not happen, but I don't know how to justify it. And shouldn't ${x_n}$ be a sequence in the new metric?, that's the starting point, in fact the def is applied with the new metric

Comment: I would say is Cauchy with the new metric just because now we have the definition writen with the new metric

Comment: The general result is closed subspaces $C$ of complete metric spaces $X$ are complete. (This is the why part of my answer, see if you can prove it!).

To answer your second question (if I understand correctly), the point of this argument is you do not know if your sequence converges in $[1, 2]$ under $d'$, the new metric. You have shown Cauchy in $([1, 2], d')$ implies Cauchy in $([1, 2], d)$ where $d$ is the usual one. Now $([1, 2], d)$ is a closed subspace of $(\mathbb{R}, d)$, so it is complete. Does this help?

Comment: sure it does, thanks!